# Trailing Zeros in printf/sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I would like to make the output of a number to always have 6 digits

e.g.:

- if number is 1 the output should be 100000
- if number is 23 the output should be 230000
- if number is 236 the output should be 236000

How can I do this with `printf`/`sprintf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

printf and its variants can pad zeroes to the left, not to the right. sprintf the number, then add the necessary zeros yourself, or make sure the number is 6 digits long:

```
while(num < 100000) 
    num *= 10;
```

(This code assumes the number isn't negative, or you're going to get in trouble)

Comment: This is easily fixed: `while ((num < 1000000) and (num > -1000000))`, but much more importantly the number must be a 32bit integer or higher, a `short` or a `char` can't hold these kinds of values.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` will return the number of character printed out. This you can print out the remaining zeros:

```
int num = 3; // init
int len = printf("%d", num);
for (int i = 0; i < 6-len; ++i)
    printf("0");
```

You should add some error checks (for example, if `len` is larger than 6).

With `sprintf`, you can use `memset` on the remaining buffer, which will be easier.

Comment: Rather than a loop, you could do `if (len >= 0 && len < 6) printf("000000" + len);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly with `printf` (at least in a standard-conforming way), you need to alter your numbers beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

As Luchian said, this behavior is unsupported in `printf`, unlike the much more common reverse (left) padding.
You could, however, easily enough generate the requested result with something like this:

```
char *number_to_six_digit_string(char *resulting_array, int number)
{
    int current_length = sprintf(resulting_array, "%d", number);
    while (6 > current_length) {
        resulting_array[current_length++] = '0';
    }
    resulting_array[current_length] = '\0';
    return resulting_array;
}
```

and then you could print the result:

```
char my_number[7];
printf("my number is %s, other stuff\n", number_to_six_digit_string(my_number, 13));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of `printf` (as in the first line of the `for` loop below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int number, width = 6;
  for (number = 1; number < 9999999; number *= 7) {
    int digits = printf("%d", number);
    if (digits < width) printf("%0*d", width-digits, 0);
    puts("");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

See code running at http://ideone.com/TolIv